# Cannot use instance member within property initializer error in DataController Init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have a data controller that is supposed to receive data, and then put it into the UITableViewDataSource. I can't seem to access the variables in init however.

If I uncomment the var sections declaration inside the init, then I get an error that "value of type DataController1 has no member sections"

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Relevant lines of code are below:

```
class DataController1: NSObject, DataController {

    struct Section {
        let type: SectionTypeEnum
        let rows: [Any]
    }

    let contactData: ContactData
    var section1: [Section1]!
    var section2: [Section2]!
    var section3: [Section3]!
//    var sections = [Section]!


    init(contactData: ContactData) {
        self.contactData = contactData

        self.section1 = self.contactData.list1
        self.section2 = self.contactData.list2
        self.section3 = self.contactData.list3

//        var sections: [Section] = [
//            Section(type: .section1, rows: section1),
//            Section(type: .section2, rows: section2),
//            Section(type: .section3, rows: section3),
//]

    }



    var sections: [Section] = [

        Section(type: .section1, rows: section1),
//Cannot use instance member 'section1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
// current error
        Section(type: .section2, rows: section2),
        Section(type: .section3, rows: section3),
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want? A stored property `[Section]` initialized in the `init` method or a property with initial value? Why is everything implicit unwrapped optional? The error occurs because you can't declare properties with initial values depending on each other

Comment: I just want to be able to access sections in the UITableViewDataSource, so I can display the table view. Sorry, I'm still new to Swift so I don't fully understand what the problem you're describing is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment *The error occurs because you can't declare properties with initial values depending on each other*.

I recommend to support only the `init(contactData` method.

**Never declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized in an `init` method with non-optional values. If they are supposed to be optional declare them as regular optional (`?`)**

```
class DataController1: NSObject, DataController {

    struct Section {
        let type: SectionTypeEnum
        let rows: [Any]
    }

    let contactData: ContactData
    var section1: [Section1]
    var section2: [Section2]
    var section3: [Section3]
    var sections: [Section]


    init(contactData: ContactData) {
        self.contactData = contactData

        section1 = self.contactData.list1
        section2 = self.contactData.list2
        section3 = self.contactData.list3
        sections = [Section(type: .section1, rows: section1),
                    Section(type: .section2, rows: section2),
                    Section(type: .section3, rows: section3)]
    }
}
```

Comment: unless necessary otherwise, I would declare section1 - section3 + sections as `let` constants..